# Splitting number and grabbing

Tags: java

If I have:

```
int money;
money = 378;
```

Now I would like to say how many banknotes and coins get out from this..

Sweden has these banknotes: 500, 100, 50, 20 and the coins 10, 5, 1

So the output i wish to get from the above `money` value:

3x100 , 1x50 , 1x20, 1x5, 3x1

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you dispose with unlimited resource of banknotes ?

Answer (score 7):

Think about how you would do it in real life. You'd *probably* start off with the highest denomination bank note, use as many of those as possible (decreasing the amount still to go), then move to the next highest, etc.

So for your example, you start off with 378. How many 500s can you use? None. So you still have 378... how many 100s can you use? 3, leaving you with 78 to go. How many 50s can you use? 1, leaving you with 28 to go etc.

You'll want some sort of collection representing the bank notes (and coins) available, and keep track of how much money you still have to represent. Think about how you want to represent the result too.

Answer (score 3):

Use divide and modulo operators. Divide by largest bill and round down, then use the result of the modulo for the next largest bill:

```
378 / 500 = 0.756 -> 0
378 % 500 = 378

378 / 100 = 3.78 -> 3
378 % 100 = 78

78 / 50 = 1.56 -> 1
78 % 50 = 28

28 / 20 = 1.4 -> 1
28 % 20 = 8

8 / 5 = 1.6 -> 1
8 % 5 = 3

3 / 1 = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a greedy algotihm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

1. sort coins available to its value [100,50,20,5,1]
2. try with max if money >= max then 100*1 , substract[ money - max ]
3. call recursively

for your example : **378**

```
378 > = 100  ---------- > 100*1
278 > = 100  -----------> 100 *1
178 > = 100  -----------> 100 *1
78 > =   50  ----------->  50 *1
28 > =   20  ----------->  20 *1
8 > =     1  ----------->   1 *1
.
.
1 > =     1  ----------->   1 *1
```

Or more optimized one

1. sort coins available to its value [100,50,20,5,1]
2. try with max if money / max >= 1 then max*result of division , money = moneybefore%max
3. call recursively

for example :

```
378 / 100 = 3.78 >=1 ------------- 3 * 100   and money = 378%100 = 78
78  / 50  = 1.0somehting >=1 -----1 * 50 and money = 78 %50 = 28
```

like wise....

Answer (score 1):

Use division and modulo :)

378 / 500 will return 0, which means that 500 does not fit into 378
378 / 100 will return 3, which means that 100 fits 3 times into 378.
When the result is larger than 0 use % to find the rest
378 % 100 will return 78
Repeat until having spent it all :)